# How is this derived? (Calculating eigenvectors of a matrix)

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm walking through an example of how to calculate the eigenvectors of a matrix, in my course book.
But I don't get one step they do, and it isn't explained at all.

[How does the top part conclude in the bottom eqautions?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEk5V.jpg)
(c is any complex constant that is not zero)

PS: Excuse me for the vague question. But I don't know what they are doing, so I don't know how to direct the question.

Comment: Please, provide more information about your question and its context, do not use just a link.

Comment: You can find a quick reference for formatting mathematical expressions using MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the equation clearly gives $v_1=0\Rightarrow v_2=0$, you pick any nonzero value for $v_1$, say $c$, and calculate what the corresponding value of $v_2$ should be (in this case we obviously use the first equation $-(1+\sqrt{5})v_1+2v_2=0$ to get $v_2=\frac12(1+\sqrt5)v_1=\frac12(1+\sqrt5)c$, which you can check also satisfies the second equation).

Comment: Okay, I understand. But should $v_1=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt 5)c$  following the same reasoning on the second equation, as supossed to $v_1=c$.

Comment: You could take $v_2 = -c$ in the bottom equation and get $v_1=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{5})c$ instead. This new vector will be a multiple of the first one. This does not matter as eigenvectors are only specified up to a none zero multiple. Their direction matters, not their magnitude.

Comment: Oh wait yeah, looked over the fact that you define both v1 and v2 at the same time. Thank you for your help